# Can you say "very thrilled"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I recently learned about strong adjectives and the fact that you shouldn't use "very" with them, because their definition already includes "very".

E.g., "thrilled" -- i.e., very happy, you can't say "very thrilled" according to the rule I described above. But for some reason this link https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/thrilled provides this example:

> I’m not very thrilled about having to do it again.

So, is the Macmillan dictionary wrong then?

Comment: I find it unfortunate that learners are getting their information from people who say "you can't do that" when there's a very wide range of opinions on the matter. I don't see why "very delighted" is wrong or stylistically bad. It may be that people think these so called (strong adjectives) convey enough intensity so that they don't need to use "very", such as in "very embarrassing"/"humiliating". The way I see it, as humiliating is not a superlative, things can be more or less humiliating. I don't get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Very thrilled" is fine. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+very+thrilled%2Cvery+thrilled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20very%20thrilled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20thrilled%3B%2Cc0) shows that it has been used for about a century, and hardly any of that usage is due to "not very thrilled".

Cf some similar phrases which are used even more often, e.g. "very excited" and "very tired".

Comment: But why? Thrilled is a strong adjective. It's the same as saying "very exhausted" which is wrong, is it not? How do I know the strong adjectives that I can use "very" with?

Comment: Google ngrams also says that people say "very exhausted".

Comment: @Pavel There’s nothing wrong with ‘very exhausted’ either. To my knowledge there is no such thing as ‘strong adjectives’. Just because the adjective _X_ is roughly equivalent to _very Y_ doesn’t mean you can’t be _very X_. That would imply that there can only ever be two degrees of a given state, which is nonsense; _very X_ would just be the same as _very, very Y_, which again is perfectly fine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what about this: https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/vocabulary-lesson-base-strong-adjectives.php there are some words here that I wouldn't use with very, such as "very boiling", or "very freezing", but are you saying that it's just a made up rule?

Comment: @Pavel Those are _absolute_ adjectives. If you use _boiling/freezing_ to just mean ‘very hot/cold’, then you can use them with _very_; but obviously not when they refer to precise temperatures (the boiling point of water, 100°C at ground-level pressure; and the freezing point of water, 0°C at ground-level pressure). Then they express absolute values that cannot logically be graded. The temperature cannot be very 0°; it either is or isn’t 0°. That page is right, though, that with ‘strong adjectives’, _absolutely_ is more common than _very_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There's a stylistic issue here: if you describe something using a strong adjective, then using yet more words in your description is fine, but a mere "very" might rather disappoint readers, given the adjective you used with it. The "very" is like a damp squib accompanying a spectacular firework.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet More Google Ngrams stats. Years 1800-2000 unless I say otherwise.

enormous/very enormous~6000 to 16000 from 1920 to 2000

huge/very huge~2000

vast/very vast~1400

large/very large~35 (up from ~20 in 1800-1840)

tired/very tired~20 to 30 from 1840 to 2000

thrilled/very thrilled~300 from 1930 to 2000. (It was much higher ~1904-1930 which is merely due to "thrilled" suddenly getting more popular before "very thrilled" caught up in the 1930s.)

Comment: @RosieF be careful relying on google ngrams. Because I just looked up "very delighted" in there and it gave me results, but those are results from dictionaries/books that teach English and saying that "very delighted" is wrong. What if there are lots of books, saying that some phrase is wrong, you look that phrase up, get many results, misleading you into thinking: "Wow, this phrase is used a lot, then it's correct". lol

Comment: I definitely find the "very delighted" example to be silly. Wouldn't "humiliating" be one for "embarrassing", and "hilarious" be one for "funny", and "appalling" be one for "bad"? If we follow this rule then we assume that it's either wrong or bad style to say "very humiliating" or "very hilarious" or "very appalling".  My feeling is that you don't find as as many examples of very (supposed strong adjective) because most people feel that adjective to be enough. These aren't superlatives so a matter of degree can still be involved, ie., things can be less or more humiliating.

Comment: I agree with Rosie F that this is a matter of style rather than the 'rule' to which the OP refers. I see nothing wrong with, say, _I'm very thrilled to be here_. But saying _I'm very ravenous_ or _I was very petrified_ or _I got very drenched on my walk this morning_ somehow weakens the adjectives rather than intensifying them.

Comment: All this data, links, sites, who is right and who is wrong  should be incorporated in the ***answer*** not lost among dozens of comments.

Comment: @RosieF Following on from pavel's comment, in more than a few of the hits for 'very thrilled' the words arise as part of constructions like 'weren't very thrilled', 'not necessarily thrilled', 'don't expect x to be very thrilled about' etc so still expressing the mordant irony of the negative construction.